# ASP.NET MVC route fails with “No type was found that matches the controller named 'Product'.”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here's the quick situation ...

I am trying to get the following url to work ...

```
http://localhost:57732/Power-Drills/DeWalt
```

I have the following Controller defined ...

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {    
        public ActionResult PowerDrills(string brandName)
        {
           ...
        }

        public ActionResult ProductLine(Int64 id)
        {
           ...
        }

    }
}
```

In the global.asax I have define the following routes ...

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PowerDrill",
        url: "Power-Drills/{brandName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "PowerDrills", brandName= "RYOBI" },
        namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication1.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

}

I am getting the following error ... "*No type was found that matches the controller named" 'Product'.*"

So it appears to be indicating that it cannot find the Product controller but ... *this* url works just fine (using the default route) and *is* handled by the Product controller ...

```
http://localhost:57732/Product/ProductLine/4
```

I have read up on routing and understand (at least I think I do) url segments, how they map to the controllers and actions and how order in the global.asax is important; I have seen and read several previous posts regarding this issue for others but their solutions have  not worked or applied to my situation (lots of Ruby for Rails posts).

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638362/asp-net-mvc-mapping-urls-different-to-controller-action-with-areas?rq=1)** post points out that the Controller class needs to inherit from "Controller" and not "ApiController" which, as you can see, mine already does.

So I am not sure what's happening and would welcome any guidance!

Thank You,

-G

Comment: Phil Haack's [Route Tester](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) is very useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: I feel liek I attempted this once a while back and had problems getting it to work. I will give it another shot though.

Comment: YEah ... I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this tool. but I referenced the RouteDebug.dll in the web project and added the call to  the Global.asax ... when I run the application ... nothing. No difference at all. It's as if it isn't there. I am sure I am not doing something right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off dropping the namespace from it and perhaps formatting your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "PowerDrill",
        "Power-Drills/{brandName}",
        new { controller = "Product", action = "PowerDrills", brandName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Though I'm not that familiar with how you have formatted your routes (with the namespace, etc), this is what I've done in MVC 3.

Try replacing your `PowerDrill` route with that.

And like Robert Harvey [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296562/asp-net-mvc-route-fails-with-no-type-was-found-that-matches-the-controller-name/11296692#comment14861840_11296562), Phil Haack's route tester is just the thing if all else fails.

Comment: Yeah ... the addition of the namespace was effort to fix the issue it started before I added it. The namespace obviously didn't fix the problem, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to keep it there.

Comment: I had a similar problem once and changing the arguments at the end, in your case brandName to UrlParameter.Optional did the trick. Though I then made sure all the links were always correct and if people went to controller/action without the /id then I just redirected them elsewhere.

Comment: I gave your suggestion a shot but to no avail :( Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed a mistake in the snippet I gave you. I've updated it accordingly.